# Always prompt for a stash message in git

Tags: bash, git, vim, version-control, git-config

I tend to stash changes without remembering why I stash them.

I do make it a point to `git stash push -m` most of the time, but if there's a fire drill or something else that knocks me out of flow, I may forget and lose time trying to recover.

Is there a way to imitate the behavior of `git commit` (minus the `-m`) for `git stash` where `vim` pops up and abandons the operation if the message is empty?

Comment: If your stashes live long enough that you forget what they’re for, they probably should be named branches instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no config option for this. You'll have to write an alias in your `.gitconfig` and train yourself to use it.

For example, I have two stash aliases `git pop` and `git save`. (You can see I didn't get the memo about `git stash save` being deprecated). These are both for convenience, and to change the default behavior to something I find more useful.

```
save = stash save -k -u
pop = stash pop
```

Unfortunately `git stash push -m` doesn't bring up an editor, if you need to write more than a few words to describe what you were doing consider a branch instead. We can fix this by writing a little shell function and passing the argument to `-m` using `"$@"` to ensure messages with spaces are a single argument.

```
savem = "!f() { git save -m \"$@\"; }; f"
```

Now you can write `git savem 'remember to remember what this was'`.

```
$ git savem 'remember to remember what this was'
Saved working directory and index state On issue/45: remember to remember what this was
```

And if you forget, you'll get the normal `git-stash` usage message. You can snazz up the alias to provide a custom usage message if you like.

```
$ git savem
usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<stash>]
...
```

Comment: This probably the best solution if I can't modify the config. I already have quite a few git aliases, so one more never hurts! Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

To me it makes sense to consider using a branch for this. It seems like you want to keep the changes. Branches can be named so it’s easier to recall what was being worked on. These can be local or pushed to remote in case it wasn’t a drill.

```
$ git branch topic/wip
```

If you want continue work on master yo can do a

```
$ git checkout master
```

Comment: In same boat as OP - branches aren't very conducive to small irrelevant changes or configurations. Using stash makes it very easy to merge in config changes and (obviously) reset to the default. With branches that can get very messy since branching largely depends on the reflog.

Comment: Agreed for anything small and irrelenvant branches doesn’t make any sense. But imitating commits through stashes..eh seems like commits could suffice.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I use branches all the time for lots of new features. Because of that I have a pretty diverse tree of commits. If I commit for irrelevant changes then I have to deal with merging or rebasing or cherry-picking, and I need to double check that I don't push my commit. It's much easier and safer to stash. Stash does the merging automatically and I don't have to worry about pushing changes I didn't mean to.

Comment: Rather than make `topic/wip`, I'd make a real topic branch (or use the one you're already on) and commit what I have with an indication in the message that it's a WIP. Less book-keeping. Then come back to it and `git commit --amend` or `git reset --soft HEAD^` (ie. "redo"). If I accidentally commit on top of the WIP commit no biggie; it will be caught by tests or in review.

Comment: @Kevin Branches in Git are the perfect tool for small changes that shouldn’t be on your current line of development. Why do you find them awkward for that?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but could be achieved using bash + vipe in moreutils

```sh
msg="$(< /dev/null vipe)";
[[ -z "$msg" ]] || git stash -m "$msg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to the original question, but for people who use [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), here is a workaround: edit or create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fugitive.vim` with this binding:

```
nmap <buffer> czz :G stash push -m '' .<Left><Left><Left>
```

This overrides the `czz` binding to stash, with the cursor ready to type a message. You can also bind it to something else (e.g. `czZ`) if you want to preserve the existing binding, but I'm not sure there's any reason to. Git seems to treat `-m ''` (empty stash message) the same as omitting the `-m` argument, and provides a default message for you.